# How to extract image name as a text?

Tags: flutter

I want to show Text widget on my image same as its name like if we have project structure something like this

```
assets/images/screenshot.jpg
```

then I want to extract 'screenshot' and display this as a Text widget..

Answer (score 1):

You could split the filename into parts like so:

```
  final filePath = 'assets/images/screenshot.jpg';
  var fileName = filePath.split('/').last; // => 'screenshot.jpg'
  var text = fileName.split('.').first; // => 'screenshot'
```